# Can the number of zeros be increased by a small change in the function

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$ and has a single zero, then is there a $g$ also continuous on $[0, 1]$ such that $f + \epsilon g$ for $\epsilon$ no matter how small increases the number of zeros for $f$.

I thought of $g$ being $\sin(1/x)$ but this isn't really continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$f(x)=\cases{x\sin(1/x^2)+2x& if $x\neq0$\\0& if $x=0$}\\g(x)=e^{500x}\cos(2\pi x)$$Then no matter how small $\epsilon$ is, we get multiple roots close to $0$. For large $\epsilon$, the two roots of $g$ will dominate.

(I haven't double checked that these two domains: small enough $\epsilon$ to give multiple solutions close to $0$ and large enough to make the roots of $g$ dominate actually overlap. I just picked $500$ on a whim and trust in the exponential function to grow fast enough.)

Comment: Your $f$ has an infinity of zeros.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter You're right. That part disappeared somewhere in the editing.